# Get value without dereferencing the pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a little bit confused with the pointer in C. My understanding is that to get a value from a pointer we need to put asterisk in the front (dereferencing). So why is the below code where I define two pointers and then assign to them what argvs point to work just fine?
However if I put asterisks in the `printf` it doesn't work?
I.e. if my arguments are `file_one` and `file_two` the output will be `file_one  file_two`

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    char *File_1, *File_2;

    File_1 = argv[1];
    File_2 = argv[2];
    printf("%s  %s\n", File_1, File_2);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'argument vector' `argv` is a pointer to a pointer (type `char**`). The assignment in the code assigns `argv[1]` (which is of type `char*`) to `File_1` (which is also of type `char*`). In total, a `char*` is copied to another `char*`. The pointers are not dereferenced any further as otherwise only one `char` would be copied, which is not desired. In C, character strings are usually implemented as `char*`, and copying of only one `char` would contradict this semantic.

Comment: Thanks Codor. Makes sense. Still confusing however as I'm new with C

Comment: @Max_S I'm *not* new to C; however still seriously confused from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *p = argv[1];
```

`agrv` is a double pointer so it can hold pointers `argv[0]` `argv[1]` and so on.

Now `argv[1]` is a pointer. So the address of this pointer is being assigned to another pointer `p` of same type `char`

Example:

```
char **p = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2);/* double pointer */

p[0] = malloc(20); /* memory allocated to single pointer */
p[1] = malloc(20); /* memory allocated to single pointer */

strcpy(p[0],"string");
strcpy(p[1],"another");

printf("%s\n",p[0]);
printf("%s\n",p[1]);
```

In 2D space

```
int **p; /* Here p is double pointer */

*p is a single pointer.
```

As already pointed out in another answer `%s` expects `char *` and you just pass the pointer of type char and allow the `printf()` to do job of dereferencing

**PS**: *p = p[0]

Answer (score 3):

From [`printf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), here's the documentation for the `s` conversion specifier (i.e `%s`):

> If no l modifier is present: The **const char *** argument is expected to
>   be a pointer to an array of character type (pointer to a string).
>   Characters from the array are written up to (but not including) a
>   terminating null byte ('\0'); if a precision is specified, no more
>   than the number specified are written. If a precision is given, no
>   null byte need be present; if the precision is not specified, or is
>   greater than the size of the array, the array must contain a
>   terminating null byte.

So basically `printf` is dereferencing it inside itself. If you do a double indirection then it may lead to UB, because:

```
 printf("%s  %s\n", *File_1, *File_2);
```

The above sends 1st char pointed by `File_1` and `File_2` and then `printf` would try to dereference it again inside thinking you sent a pointer to char when you actually sent a char.

Answer (score 0):

Try to visualise what this looks like in memory:
`char** argv` is a pointer to a pointer, both pointers happen to point to the beginning of an array. The first array looks like `[0][1]` where each item is a pointer to a `char *`:

```
[0] -> ["file_one"]
[1] -> ["file_two"]
```

Where `["file_one"]` is actually just a pointer to `'f'` in memory, so we have `'f', 'i', 'l', 'e', '_', 'o', 'n', 'e', '\0'` next to each other in memory and the null byte `'\0'` tells us where the array ends.

So when you assign:

```
char * File_1 = argv[1];
```

Your `File_1` now contains a pointer to that first `f` and when we use `printf`:

```
printf("%s  %s\n", File_1, File_2);
```

It takes that `char *`, assumes it is a null terminated string, and dereferences the pointer at consecutive memory locations until it hits the null byte in order to read in the contents of the string.

Answer (score -1):

`File_1` is a pointer to `char` variable.

while when you de-reference it using `*File_1`, you refer to a `char` not a `char *`.

Since `printf` uses `%s` for strings i.e. `char *` therefore, to print `*File_1` you should use `%c`.